# Upload image from device to google folder and create image URL in google sheet active cell

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheet, I found a script to upload image from the device to google folder, and then create an image URL in the active cell. Below is the script:

### Code.gs

```
function addImage() {
  var filename = 'Row';
  var htmlTemp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index');
  htmlTemp.fName = filename;
  htmlTemp.position = 2;
  var html = htmlTemp.evaluate().setHeight(96).setWidth(415);
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.showModalDialog(html, 'Upload');
}

function upload(obj, rowNum) {
  var newFileName = obj[2];
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(...obj);
  var upFile = DriveApp.getFolderById('[folder_id]').createFile(blob).setName(newFileName);
  var fileUrl = upFile.getUrl();
  var urlCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange(rowNum, 5);
  urlCell.setValue('=HYPERLINK("' + fileUrl + '","View image")');
  return "Done.";
}
```

### Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base target="_center">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="myForm">
    Please upload an image below.<br /><br />
    <input type="hidden" name="fname" id="fname" value="<?= fName ?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="position" id="position" value="<?= position ?>"/>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" accept="image/jpeg,.pdf" />
    <input type="button" value="Submit" class="action" onclick="formData(this.parentNode)" />
    <input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />
  </form>
  <script>
    // Disable the default submit action using “func1”
    window.onload = func1;
    function func1() {
      document.getElementById('myForm').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
      });
    }

    function formData(obj) {
      const file = obj.file.files[0];
      const fr = new FileReader();
      fr.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
      fr.onload = f =>
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(closeIt).upload([[...new Int8Array(f.target.result)], file.type, obj.fname.value], obj.position.value);
    }

    function closeIt(e) {
      console.log(e);
      google.script.host.close();
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I ran the `addImage()` function, a dialog box popped up in which I uploaded an image from the device, but when I clicked on the submit button, it did not do anything and stuck there. How should I fix the script so that the "Submit" button will function as what I want? Any help or advise will be greatly appreciated!

This is my google sheet link:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1D-umFA8pnWJlXipuBOIPkE7fXB3TID3zbHUWSZANeIs/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I saw your showing script in your question and your current script in your provided Spreadsheet, I noticed that the file ID is used as `[folder_id]` of `var upFile = DriveApp.getFolderById('[folder_id]').createFile(blob).setName(newFileName);`. I guessed that the reason for your current issue might be due to this. In this case, `[folder_id]` cannot be used. Please modify `[folder_id]` to `folder_id`. So, please modify your script in your Spreadsheet as follows.

#### From:

```
var upFile = DriveApp.getFolderById('[1mAE###]').createFile(blob).setName(newFileName);
```

#### To:

```
var upFile = DriveApp.getFolderById('1mAE###').createFile(blob).setName(newFileName);
```

- When I tested your script by modifying this, I confirmed that the script works and the file could be uploaded, and the file link is put into column "E".

#### Note:

- As additional information, when you confirm the error message from the Google Apps Script side, you can use `withFailureHandler` as follows. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withFailureHandler(Function))

  ```js
  google.script.run
    .withFailureHandler(err => console.log(err.message))
    .withSuccessHandler(closeIt)
    .upload([[...new Int8Array(f.target.result)], file.type, obj.fname.value], obj.position.value);
  ```

#### Reference:

- [getFolderById(id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getFolderById(String))

Comment: Hi Tanaike, thanks for your help, the solution works fine for me. However, when I copy all the code to another google sheet under another google account, then it doesn't work again. The sharing option for both folder and google sheet are the same, I just change the folder_id to another one and it failed.  This is the new google sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KQAFHrgrJNimr4u_rdWbBZMxnBUePXQnSPxYuz-Om60/edit#gid=210056067

I'm not sure why the same script work in one sheet but not the other, thank you.

Comment: I'm also uploading the same image, but it works fine in the first google sheet (the link in my question), but not the second one (the link in the comment above).

Comment: @weizer Thank you for replying. From `thanks for your help, the solution works fine for me.`, I understood that my answer resolved your issue.

Comment: @weizer About your new question `I'm also uploading the same image, but it works fine in the first google sheet (the link in my question), but not the second one (the link in the comment above).`, when I saw your new Spreadsheet, it seems that you are using the folder ID as `1joxT2uCWqlN-####################?lfhs=2`. In this case, please remove `?lfhs=2`. I thought that from the length of `1joxT2uCWqlN-####################?lfhs=2`, your new folder ID might be `1joxT2uCWqlN-####################`. But, I'm not sure about your new situation. So, if this was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: @weizer For example, when the URL of the folder is `https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/#################################` and `https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/#################################?xxx=yyy`, the folder ID is `#################################`.

Comment: Thanks Tanaike, now it works fine for me! I realized that the image URL will always be located in row 2 column 5 regardless of where is the active cell, may I know is this issue can be solved? Meaning the image URL will be located wherever the active cell is. This is what I mean in my question title as well.

Comment: @weizer Thank you for replying. From `now it works fine for me!`, I understood that your 2nd question was resolved. About your 3rd question `I realized that the image URL will always be located in row 2 column 5 regardless of where is the active cell, may I know is this issue can be solved?`, I think that in your script, your 3rd issue is due to `htmlTemp.position = 2;`. For example, how about modifying `htmlTemp.position = 2;` to `htmlTemp.position = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getRow();`? By this, the value is put into column "E" of the active cell.

Comment: Thanks, Tanaike, now it is 100% achieved what I desired, appreciate your help so much!

Comment: @weizer Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issues were resolved. Thank you, too.